# Using NodeJS plugins in Electron

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I am new to Electron (Atom-shell), and I am trying to load a NodeJS plugin into the application I am building, but I don't know how. The documentation is not clear on that.

For instance, I am trying to use sqlite3 plugin in my app, I used `npm install sqlite3`, and it was successfully installed. But the application throws and error when I try to call it `var sqlite = require('sqlite3')`. Are there any further steps I am not aware of ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For pure JS (i.e. not native) modules you need the following:

1. Have the module listed in your `package.json` dependencies
2. Let electron know where to find the module (e.g. `export NODE_PATH=/PATH/TO/node_module`)

The first requirement is obvious and the second has its roots in [this issue](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1390).

For native node modules (such as `sqlite3`) which use C++ bindings, you need to build them against electron headers to work. According to [electron docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md), the easiest way to do that would be:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

# Every time you run npm install, run this
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears so much for me. Right now I am struggling with the "gyp" thing, more troubles with the python version and the C++ installation. I cannot understand why on earth thing are this hard. That's what is wrong with open-source stuff :(

Comment: Glad I could help! Creating cross platform applications is hard, no matter open source or not. Take a look at [this article](http://quaintous.com/2015/06/12/node-gyp-for-non-cpp-programmers/), it might help you with node-gyp.

Answer (score 1):

To install the npm modules correctly you should go into the folder of your electron app and install the module via npm.

```
npm install --save sqlite3
```

The flag --save is important, because npm will install the module inside your app.

Afterwards the require should work.

Comment: Thanks, but as it turned out, this works fine only with non-native node module, the native ones require further work (Installing python and Visual Studio for some reason).