# How to use sqlite3 module with electron?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

I want to develop desktop app using [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) that uses sqlite3 package installed via npm with the command

```
npm install --save sqlite3
```

but it gives the following error in electron browser console

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'E:\allcode\eapp\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v45-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
```

My development environment is windows 8.1 x64
node version 12.7

my **package.json** file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "eapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.32.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.5",   
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js file**

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window'); 
require('crash-reporter').start();
var mainWindow = null;


app.on('window-all-closed', function() {  
    if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600}); 
    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');   
    mainWindow.openDevTools();  
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {       
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

**my.js file**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');

db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE if not exists lorem (info TEXT)");

    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
    }
    stmt.finalize();

    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
        console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
    });
});

db.close();
```

**index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div >
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<!--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/my.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 145):

By far the easiest way to use SQLite with electron is with `electron-builder`.

First, add a postinstall step in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
   ...
}
```

and then install the necessary dependencies and build:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm install --save sqlite3
npm run postinstall
```

electron-builder will build the native module for your platform, with the correct name for the Electron binding; and you can then `require` it in code as normal.

See my [github repo](https://github.com/sjmelia/electron-boilerplate-sqlite) and [blog post](http://blog.arrayofbytes.co.uk/?p=379) - it took me quite a while to figure this out too.

Comment: Using your [electron-boilerplate-sqlite](https://github.com/sjmelia/electron-boilerplate-sqlite) is indeed the easier method, but with `npm install`

Comment: when run 'npm run postinstall', i got this error "Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch."

Comment: This has saved my hide not once, but twice so far!

Comment: Does anyone know whether the `--save sqlite3` option can be reliably tagged onto the first line (with `--save-dev electron-builder`), where `npm install` would only be run once?

Comment: This does not work for me, I get errors like ` ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:67:18: error: ‘class Nan::Persistent<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘MarkIndependent’`

Comment: The easiest way to use sqlite3 with electron apps is to follow sqlite3 documentation here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#custom-builds-and-electron. Works for me on electron 8.3.0, no rebuild required. I'm just giving more visibility to Sailab Rahi's answer.

Comment: I installed these dependencies and now nom run start does not work anymore.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"` ?

Answer (score 21):

I would not recommend the native node sqlite3 module. It requires being rebuild to work with electron. This is a massive pain to do - At least I can never get it to work and their a no instructions to for rebuilding modules on windows.

Instead have a look at kripken's 'sql.js' module which is sqlite3 that has been compiled 100% in JavaScript.  https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/

Comment: Electron docs are pretty clear that in order to use bundled native modules, you are required to rebuild them in order to work with electron.  Either use the electron-rebuild utility which works most of the time or manually set the gyp flags: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/

Comment: mate if you can point me in the direction of the windows version of the rebuild documentation along with how to get the builder hooked up to VS compiler that would be grate.  As it stands I can't find any documentation that exists, is easy to find or easy to follow.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild is a handy tool for rebuilding in development.  https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Multi-Platform-Build describes a multi-platform build strategy for production builds.  Jut remember, once you introduce native deps, you lose the ability to cross compile for different OSs. https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation has decent docs on necessary windows compiler tools.

Comment: none of these comments are relevant to this answer!

Comment: It should be mentioned that sql.js can not operate on the filesystem. Everytime you need to change the database you have to write the whole thing to disk. Making it pretty much useless for most scenarios.

Comment: so they have now fixed a number of issues with re-compiling modules on windows. They added Visual Studio 2015 C/C++ compiler support to node-gyp so you don't need to find, configure and install visual studio 2010 and mSoft released the 2015 compiler as a standalone install. See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245 for more info.

Comment: But it explicitly says: "If you are building a native application in javascript (using Electron for instance), or are working in node.js, you will likely prefer to use a native binding of SQLite to javascript."

Comment: sql.js its more like a toy, made for fun. It cannot be better than NeDB and other nosql databases, because its store all database in memory. So there is no good reason to use it. For small database use nosql like NeDB, for larger you have to compile sqlite

Comment: I would assume that one can use sql.js and keep a dump of the database in the local storage or even remotely, which is still great.

Comment: also just to mention sql.js is useless if you rely on the sqlcipher extension to sqlite

Answer (score 12):

Two aspects are to be considered here:

1. Setting `NODE_PATH`: this lets electron know where to find your modules (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32335874/2295964) for a thorough explanation)
2. Compiling native modules against electron headers: see official [docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md)

And checkout the following questions, that ask the same thing:

- [Electron App with Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220970/electron-app-with-database)
- [Using NodeJS plugins in Elelectron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406397/using-nodejs-plugins-in-elelectron/32415283)

---

**My tip** would be to give [lovefield](https://github.com/google/lovefield) (by Google) a try.

Comment: In Nodewebkit, I must compile the sqlite. Same rule apply for the electron?

Comment: @Wexoni AFAIK every node module with native bindings must be compiled against electron headers.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but the way I understand it... same rule apply for Electron and for NW?

Comment: @Wexoni I haven't worked with NW, but I know that `sqlite3` must be compiled before being able to use it in electron. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Yes. You have answered my question :)

Comment: The link to the official docs had instructions that worked for me.  I think it's the same suggestion as the answer below.

Comment: Any news with Electron 1.0?

Comment: @YannBertrand they still use own headers. So i suppose you'd still need to compile it against their headers.

Comment: Thanks for your tip lovefield. It's really a great library.

Comment: @YanFoto The first question you linked doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install --save sqlite3
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
```

Then, in the scripts of your package.json, add this line:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "electron-rebuild",
  ...
},
```

Then just re-install to trigger the post-install:

```
npm install
```

Works flawlessly for me in a complex use case also involving electron-builder, electron-webpack and sequelize.

It works in electron-webpack's dev mode and in production mode for both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 8):

I was having same problem. Tried everything and atlast this worked for me :-

```
npm install --save sqlite3
npm install --save electron-rebuild
npm install --save electron-prebuilt
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
```

This will create "electron-v1.3-win32-x64" folder in .\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\  location which is used by electron to use sqlite3.

Just start application and you will be able to use sqlite3 now.

Comment: It just created an empty folder, but still no `node_sqlite3.node` file in it

Comment: electron-prebuilt has been renamed to electron. For more details, see http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/08/16/npm-install-electron

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution:

1. Install electron-rebuild `npm i electron-rebuild --save-dev`
2. Launch electron-rebuild `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` (or `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd` on windows)
3. Go to "**node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/**" and rename the folder "**electron-v0.36-darwin-x64**" to "**node-*v47*-darwin-x64**"

PS: *v47* is my version, be careful to choose the good one (in your case *v45*)

Comment: Can you explain the third step? Why rename?

Comment: I don't remember exactly now but probably because the end of the path was hardcoded. It's looking for something like `node-v${version}-darwin-x64`.

Comment: Lol thank you for replying after 4 years @fabien-sa. It reminded me how much I've grown since then. Now I'm maintaining my own SQLite3 library. 

Answer (score 5):

It works for me in version 3 and 4, unfortunately NOT version 5.  See the sqlite3 documentation for details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#custom-builds-and-electron or otherwise run the following line: `npm install sqlite3 --runtime=electron --target=4.0.0 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron`

Comment: That was my problem with sqlite3 and electron8.3.0, and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38910849/2519089)

**TL;DR**

```
cd .\node_modules\sqlite3
npm install nan --save
npm run prepublish
node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.3-win32-x64
node-gyp rebuild --target=1.3.2 --arch=x64 --target_platform=win32 --dist-url=http://electron.atom.io/ --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.3-win32-x64
```

Comment: what the script `prepublish` looks like?

Comment: linked similar answer is 404

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this error too. Here is how i solve it:

`npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild`

then:

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`

from: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

ps: While it's on rebuilding, don't use `npm start`to lanch the electron app. Otherwise the rebuild process would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build the native modules using visual studio.

1. Download visual studio 2019.
2. Install package "desktop development with c++". In installation details tab select 
   "MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)"
3. Download electron-builder in your project.
4. In package.json create a script.
   "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
     }
5. then run the script.