# Using npm modules with electron and webpack?

Tags: sqlite, npm, webpack, electron

I want to use sqlite3 with this boilerplate:

https://github.com/bradstewart/electron-boilerplate-vue

I've tried a lot of ways getting require('sqlite3'), to work, but it keeps failing with the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
```

- global.require() did not work
- adding it to the webpack.ExternalsPlugin in `builds/webpack.base.conf.js` did not help

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This should be able to help you: [How to use sqlite3 module with electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504307/how-to-use-sqlite3-module-with-electron)

Basically:

1. Install electron-rebuild: `npm i electron-rebuild --save-dev`
2. Launch `electron-rebuild ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` (or
   `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd` on windows)
3. Go to "node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/" and rename the folder
   "electron-v0.36-darwin-x64" to "node-v47-darwin-x64"

Comment: If you format the answer using our markup system its going to be a lot better.

Comment: @karlphillip is that good for you? Sorry, I'm quite new here lol.

Comment: Its better, yes. +1

Comment: this is not the problem, the problem is webpack. I cannot require() any node modules because it overrides the node require function...

Comment: @Artisan72 have you set the NODE_PATH? If not, try that. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling sqlite3? I also assume you've tried [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html)