# Connecting electron with sqlite3

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to connect electron with sqlite3. My package.json file is listed below

```
{
  "name": "electrontest2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "db.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },

"scripts": {
"start": "electron ."
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

But while doing npm start it is throwing this error

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:47:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:47:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
```

I think I am getting this error as i am having :

'/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v46-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'

instead of

'/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'

Please tell where I am making mistake. Currently while running the app it is throwing the error listed above.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved.  I'm running into the exact same problem.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504307/how-to-use-sqlite3-module-with-electron (?)

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that the error is because the compiled SQLite module is named for Node by default; and thus Electron can't find it. Using `node-gyp` to rebuild with the correct name, as in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37779713/5608540) should work; but it's a lot easier to use the npm package `electron-builder` which will give you a better workflow and work with multiple platforms and versions without having to add scripts for `node-gyp`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230765/5608540) to a similar question which details how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding the sqlite3 package as follows:

```
cd node_modules/sqlite3
npm run prepublish
node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64
node-gyp rebuild --target=0.37.2 --arch=x64 --target_platform=linux --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64
```

Check what is you electron version

```
electron -v
```

Replace --target value with the vesion of your electron package.

Comment: Thanks @LuisPinto, I run all the codes listed, in the terminal (Ubuntu 14.04). But It did not fix the problem. It creates a new folder node-v47-linux-x64 inside /var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/ . I guess we need this folder "electron-v1.2-linux-x64" inside this path  "/var/www/tools/node/project/electrontest2/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/ " to fix the problem. Please tell how to do so ?? Please rectify me if I am doing any mistake. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Node Version : v4.4.5, NPM Version : 2.15.5

Comment: Please tell which sqlite3 version is compatible with electron 1.2.2 build. I tried something like..  
cd node_modules/sqlite3
npm run prepublish
node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64
node-gyp rebuild --target=0.27.1 --arch=x64 --target_platform=darwin --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=../lib/binding/electron-v1.2-linux-x64
But it is throwing 
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 43. I think it is some version issue.Please help regarding where i am making mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running this with the latest Node version (6.2.2), if you are using an older version eg. the 4.2 then you will get an older bundle instead of the v48 your electron will need:

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

And simply renamed the folder in node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding from node-v48-linux-x64 to electron-v1.2-linux-x64.

It started complaining about requiring callbacks were they are supposed to be optional, but I just added them like this and it worked:

```
var stmt = db.prepare(
  "INSERT INTO discount VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
  [1,2,3],
  () => true //Expected callback that is supposed to be optional
);
```

I just needed the Sqlite in my electron app for simple purposes and didn't have any other problems in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First add new postinstall script in your package.json

`"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
    }`

Then install it using :

`npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm install --save sqlite3
npm run postinstall`

You can also find the same at : 
[Electron application SQLITE package has not been found installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696374/electron-application-sqlite-package-has-not-been-found-installed)