# Electron application SQLITE package has not been found installed

Tags: electron, electron-builder

We are struggling with building app for windows 32bit and 64bit.

It is angular 2 application which uses sqlite3 as a database.

Everything works perfectly in a development but after packaging app and running it on windows it throwns error

```
SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install sqlite3 --save
```

Here is package.json ( part of it which is important for this issue ):

```
 "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean --force && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "node": "node",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps && electron-rebuild",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "electron:pre": "copyfiles main.js dist && copyfiles package.json dist && copyfiles ./icons/* ./dist && npm --prefix ./dist install ./dist --production",
    "electron:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron .",
    "electron:prod": "npm run build:aot:prod && npm run electron:pre && electron ./dist",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:aot:prod && npm run electron:pre && node package.js --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64 && cd dist && electron-builder install-app-deps --platform=linux --arch=x64",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:aot:prod && npm run electron:pre && electron-builder install-app-deps --platform=win32 &&  node package.js --asar --platform=win32",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:aot:prod && npm run electron:pre && node package.js --asar --platform=darwin --arch=x64 && cd dist && electron-builder install-app-deps --platform=darwin --arch=x64",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.6.38",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.9",
    "typeorm": "0.1.0-alpha.49",
    "uikit": "^3.0.0-beta.30"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^4.0.5",
    "@ngrx/store": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.39",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.16",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "electron": "1.7.5",
    "electron-builder": "^19.27.7",
    "electron-packager": "8.7.2",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.6.0",
    "electron-reload": "^1.1.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "^3.0.2",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "~1.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "tslint": "~4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "2.5.0",
    "uglify-js": "git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony-v2.8.22",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "~2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
  },
```

After running `npm run electron:windows` everything is good and here is output:

/home/haris/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/bin/node /home/haris/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run electron:windows --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

```
> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 electron:windows /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> npm run build:aot:prod && npm run electron:pre && electron-builder install-app-deps --platform=win32 &&  node package.js --asar --platform=win32


> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 build:aot:prod /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail


> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 clean:dist /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> npm run rimraf -- dist


> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 rimraf /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> rimraf "dist"


> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 clean:aot /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> npm run rimraf -- compiled


> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 rimraf /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> rimraf "compiled"


> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 webpack /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "config/webpack.prod.js" "--progress" "--profile" "--bail"

Starting compilation using the angular compiler.
Angular compilation done, starting webpack bundling.
  0% compiling
 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...ntent-manager/src/main.browser.aot.ts
 10% building modules 0/2 modules 2 active ...tent-manager/src/polyfills.browser.ts
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.5.0 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-/tsconfig.webpack.json.


 10% building modules 1/2 modules 1 active ...tent-manager/src/polyfills.browser.ts

# I removed building modules proccess because of limit of characters on stackoverflow.


25067ms additional asset processing
 92% chunk asset optimization
3538ms chunk asset optimization
 94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Ok, 2.38 sec.

2788ms asset optimization
 95% emitting
18ms emitting
Hash: a3f29d769fb284afcae1
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 62001ms
     [emitted]         


WARNING in ./~/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
33:19-32 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js
37:23-85 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    [3IRH] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:36ms building:174ms = 210ms
    [7GO9] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 2.2 kB {0} [built]
            factory:6ms building:11ms = 17ms
    [DuR2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:36ms building:174ms = 210ms
    [M4fF] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:83ms building:3556ms = 3639ms
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    [9rjH] ./~/css-loader!./src/styles/headings.css 166 bytes {0} [built]
            factory:2ms building:17ms = 19ms
    [FZ+f] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:0ms building:2ms = 2ms
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    [FZ+f] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.26 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:0ms building:1ms = 1ms
    [pZge] ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/styles.less 256 kB {0} [built]
            factory:3ms building:5063ms = 5066ms

> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 electron:pre /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-
> copyfiles main.js dist && copyfiles package.json dist && copyfiles ./icons/* ./dist && npm --prefix ./dist install ./dist --production


> sqlite3@3.1.13 install /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-/dist/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[sqlite3] Success: "/home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-/dist/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" is installed via remote

> angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 postinstall /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-/dist
> install-app-deps && electron-rebuild

Warning: Please use as subcommand: electron-builder install-app-deps
electron-builder 19.36.0
Rebuilding native production dependencies for linux:x64
✔ Rebuild Complete
angular-electron-starter@1.0.0 /home/haris/development/walter/bitbucket-/dist
├─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.38 
│ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3 
│ │ ├── boom@2.10.1 
│ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5 
│ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3 
│ │ └── sntp@1.0.9 
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ ├─┬ nopt@4.0.1 
│ │ ├── abbrev@1.1.1 
│ │ └─┬ osenv@0.1.4 
│ │   ├── os-homedir@1.0.2 
│ │   └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ npmlog@4.1.2 
│ │ ├─┬ are-we-there-yet@1.1.4 
│ │ │ └── delegates@1.0.0 
│ │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0 
│ │ ├─┬ gauge@2.7.4 
│ │ │ ├── aproba@1.2.0 
│ │ │ ├── has-unicode@2.0.1 
│ │ │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1 
│ │ │ ├── signal-exit@3.0.2 
│ │ │ ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
│ │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1 
│ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
│ │ │ └── wide-align@1.1.2 
│ │ └── set-blocking@2.0.0 
│ ├─┬ rc@1.2.1 
│ │ ├── deep-extend@0.4.2 
│ │ ├── ini@1.3.4 
│ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ └── strip-json-comments@2.0.1 
│ ├─┬ request@2.81.0 
│ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0 
│ │ ├── aws4@1.6.0 
│ │ ├── caseless@0.12.0 
│ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
│ │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
│ │ ├── extend@3.0.1 
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@2.1.4 
│ │ │ └── asynckit@0.4.0 
│ │ ├─┬ har-validator@4.2.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ ajv@4.11.8 
│ │ │ │ ├── co@4.6.0 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ json-stable-stringify@1.0.1 
│ │ │ │   └── jsonify@0.0.0 
│ │ │ └── har-schema@1.0.5 
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1 
│ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0 
│ │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.4.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.3.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.3 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ verror@1.10.0 
│ │ │ │   └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.13.1 
│ │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3 
│ │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │ │   ├── bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1 
│ │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.14.1 
│ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
│ │ │   ├─┬ getpass@0.1.7 
│ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.1 
│ │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.5 
│ │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
│ │ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.17 
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.30.0 
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2 
│ │ ├── performance-now@0.2.0 
│ │ ├── qs@6.4.0 
│ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
│ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
│ │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@2.3.3 
│ │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1 
│ │ ├── tunnel-agent@0.6.0 
│ │ └── uuid@3.1.0 
│ ├── semver@5.4.1 
│ ├─┬ tar@2.2.1 
│ │ ├── block-stream@0.0.9 
│ │ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.11 
│ │ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.11 
│ │ └── inherits@2.0.3 
│ └─┬ tar-pack@3.4.0 
│   ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
│   │ └── ms@2.0.0 
│   ├── fstream-ignore@1.0.5 
│   ├─┬ once@1.4.0 
│   │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 
│   ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.3 
│   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│   │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 
│   │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
│   │ ├── string_decoder@1.0.3 
│   │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│   └── uid-number@0.0.6 
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.10 
├─┬ rimraf@2.6.2 
│ └─┬ glob@7.1.2 
│   ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
│   ├── inflight@1.0.6 
│   ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4 
│   │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.8 
│   │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0 
│   │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
│   └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
├─┬ sqlite3@3.1.13 
│ ├── nan@2.7.0 
│ └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.38 
│   ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3 
│   │ ├── boom@2.10.1 
│   │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5 
│   │ ├── hoek@2.16.3 
│   │ └── sntp@1.0.9 
│   ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│   │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│   ├─┬ nopt@4.0.1 
│   │ ├── abbrev@1.1.1 
│   │ └─┬ osenv@0.1.4 
│   │   ├── os-homedir@1.0.2 
│   │   └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
│   ├─┬ npmlog@4.1.2 
│   │ ├─┬ are-we-there-yet@1.1.4 
│   │ │ └── delegates@1.0.0 
│   │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0 
│   │ ├─┬ gauge@2.7.4 
│   │ │ ├── aproba@1.2.0 
│   │ │ ├── has-unicode@2.0.1 
│   │ │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1 
│   │ │ ├── signal-exit@3.0.2 
│   │ │ ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2 
│   │ │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
│   │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.1 
│   │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1 
│   │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
│   │ │ └── wide-align@1.1.2 
│   │ └── set-blocking@2.0.0 
│   ├─┬ rc@1.2.1 
│   │ ├── deep-extend@0.4.2 
│   │ ├── ini@1.3.4 
│   │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│   │ └── strip-json-comments@2.0.1 
│   ├─┬ request@2.81.0 
│   │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0 
│   │ ├── aws4@1.6.0 
│   │ ├── caseless@0.12.0 
│   │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
│   │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
│   │ ├── extend@3.0.1 
│   │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
│   │ ├─┬ form-data@2.1.4 
│   │ │ └── asynckit@0.4.0 
│   │ ├─┬ har-validator@4.2.1 
│   │ │ ├─┬ ajv@4.11.8 
│   │ │ │ ├── co@4.6.0 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ json-stable-stringify@1.0.1 
│   │ │ │   └── jsonify@0.0.0 
│   │ │ └── har-schema@1.0.5 
│   │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1 
│   │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0 
│   │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.4.1 
│   │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│   │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.3.0 
│   │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.3 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ verror@1.10.0 
│   │ │ │   └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│   │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.13.1 
│   │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3 
│   │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│   │ │   ├── bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1 
│   │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.14.1 
│   │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│   │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
│   │ │   ├─┬ getpass@0.1.7 
│   │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│   │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.1 
│   │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.5 
│   │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
│   │ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
│   │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
│   │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.17 
│   │ │ └── mime-db@1.30.0 
│   │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2 
│   │ ├── performance-now@0.2.0 
│   │ ├── qs@6.4.0 
│   │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
│   │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
│   │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@2.3.3 
│   │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1 
│   │ ├── tunnel-agent@0.6.0 
│   │ └── uuid@3.1.0 
│   ├─┬ rimraf@2.6.2 
│   │ └─┬ glob@7.1.2 
│   │   ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
│   │   ├── inflight@1.0.6 
│   │   ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4 
│   │   │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.8 
│   │   │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0 
│   │   │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
│   │   └── path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
│   ├── semver@5.4.1 
│   ├─┬ tar@2.2.1 
│   │ ├── block-stream@0.0.9 
│   │ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.11 
│   │ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.11 
│   │ └── inherits@2.0.3 
│   └─┬ tar-pack@3.4.0 
│     ├─┬ debug@2.6.9 
│     │ └── ms@2.0.0 
│     ├── fstream-ignore@1.0.5 
│     ├─┬ once@1.4.0 
│     │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 
│     ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.3 
│     │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│     │ ├── isarray@1.0.0 
│     │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
│     │ ├── string_decoder@1.0.3 
│     │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│     └── uid-number@0.0.6 
├─┬ typeorm@0.1.0-alpha.49 
│ ├── app-root-path@2.0.1 
│ ├─┬ chalk@2.1.0 
│ │ ├─┬ ansi-styles@3.2.0 
│ │ │ └─┬ color-convert@1.9.0 
│ │ │   └── color-name@1.1.3 
│ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
│ │ └─┬ supports-color@4.4.0 
│ │   └── has-flag@2.0.0 
│ ├─┬ cli-highlight@1.1.4 
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
│ │ │ ├── has-ansi@2.0.0 
│ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
│ │ ├── he@1.1.1 
│ │ ├── highlight.js@9.12.0 
│ │ ├─┬ mz@2.7.0 
│ │ │ ├── any-promise@1.3.0 
│ │ │ └─┬ thenify-all@1.6.0 
│ │ │   └── thenify@3.3.0 
│ │ └─┬ yargs@4.8.1 
│ │   ├── lodash.assign@4.2.0 
│ │   ├── os-locale@1.4.0 
│ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1 
│ │   │ ├─┬ find-up@1.1.2 
│ │   │ │ ├── path-exists@2.1.0 
│ │   │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
│ │   │ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4 
│ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0 
│ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0 
│ │   │   │ └─┬ strip-bom@2.0.0 
│ │   │   │   └── is-utf8@0.2.1 
│ │   │   └── path-type@1.1.0 
│ │   ├── which-module@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── window-size@0.2.0 
│ │   └─┬ yargs-parser@2.4.1 
│ │     └── camelcase@3.0.0 
│ ├── dotenv@4.0.0 
│ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.10.0 
│ │ ├─┬ argparse@1.0.9 
│ │ │ └── sprintf-js@1.0.3 
│ │ └── esprima@4.0.0 
│ ├─┬ xml2js@0.4.19 
│ │ ├── sax@1.2.4 
│ │ └── xmlbuilder@9.0.4 
│ ├─┬ yargonaut@1.1.2 
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
│ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
│ │ ├── figlet@1.2.0 
│ │ └── parent-require@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ yargs@9.0.1 
│   ├── camelcase@4.1.0 
│   ├─┬ cliui@3.2.0 
│   │ └── wrap-ansi@2.1.0 
│   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 
│   ├── get-caller-file@1.0.2 
│   ├─┬ os-locale@2.1.0 
│   │ ├─┬ execa@0.7.0 
│   │ │ ├─┬ cross-spawn@5.1.0 
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ lru-cache@4.1.1 
│   │ │ │ │ ├── pseudomap@1.0.2 
│   │ │ │ │ └── yallist@2.1.2 
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ shebang-command@1.2.0 
│   │ │ │ │ └── shebang-regex@1.0.0 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ which@1.3.0 
│   │ │ │   └── isexe@2.0.0 
│   │ │ ├── get-stream@3.0.0 
│   │ │ ├── is-stream@1.1.0 
│   │ │ ├─┬ npm-run-path@2.0.2 
│   │ │ │ └── path-key@2.0.1 
│   │ │ ├── p-finally@1.0.0 
│   │ │ └── strip-eof@1.0.0 
│   │ ├─┬ lcid@1.0.0 
│   │ │ └── invert-kv@1.0.0 
│   │ └─┬ mem@1.1.0 
│   │   └── mimic-fn@1.1.0 
│   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@2.0.0 
│   │ ├─┬ find-up@2.1.0 
│   │ │ └─┬ locate-path@2.0.0 
│   │ │   ├─┬ p-locate@2.0.0 
│   │ │   │ └── p-limit@1.1.0 
│   │ │   └── path-exists@3.0.0 
│   │ └─┬ read-pkg@2.0.0 
│   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@2.0.0 
│   │   │ ├─┬ parse-json@2.2.0 
│   │   │ │ └─┬ error-ex@1.3.1 
│   │   │ │   └── is-arrayish@0.2.1 
│   │   │ ├── pify@2.3.0 
│   │   │ └── strip-bom@3.0.0 
│   │   ├─┬ normalize-package-data@2.4.0 
│   │   │ ├── hosted-git-info@2.5.0 
│   │   │ ├─┬ is-builtin-module@1.0.0 
│   │   │ │ └── builtin-modules@1.1.1 
│   │   │ └─┬ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1 
│   │   │   ├─┬ spdx-correct@1.0.2 
│   │   │   │ └── spdx-license-ids@1.2.2 
│   │   │   └── spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4 
│   │   └── path-type@2.0.0 
│   ├── require-directory@2.1.1 
│   ├── require-main-filename@1.0.1 
│   ├─┬ string-width@2.1.1 
│   │ ├── is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
│   │ └─┬ strip-ansi@4.0.0 
│   │   └── ansi-regex@3.0.0 
│   ├── which-module@2.0.0 
│   ├── y18n@3.2.1 
│   └── yargs-parser@7.0.0 
└── uikit@3.0.0-beta.30 

electron-builder 19.36.0
Rebuilding native production dependencies for win32:x64
Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v1.7.5
Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v1.7.5
Application packaged successfully! [ 'app-builds/angular-electron-starter-win32-ia32',
  'app-builds/angular-electron-starter-win32-x64' ]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I run .exe on windows I'm getting error that I mentioned above how sqlite package has not been found.

Comment: Same issue I'm facing with

Answer (score 5):

SQLite3 is a native Node.js module so it can't be used directly with Electron without rebuilding it to target Electron.The electron-builder will build the native module for our platform and we can then require it in code as normal.

The following are steps you need to follow.

First, we need to add a postinstall step in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
   ...
    }
```

and then install the necessary dependencies and build:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm install --save sqlite3
npm run postinstall
```

I have used this same procedure in windows 7(32 bit) and also Windows 10(64 bit). I did not face any problem regarding this.