# How do I fix these runtime errors after building the SQLite module for Electron?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I have a trouble with a sqlite3 module for electron. I had been looking about this problem before ask, but any answer has solved my problem.

I have installed this module in electron in a some computers, in first place the module don't works and appears the next error:

> "Cannot find module .../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v1.4-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node"

I have seen in another stackoverflow thread that I should rename the folder node-v48-linux-x64 to electron-v1.4-linux-x64, this problem in a few computers have been solved. But in other computers I have another problem:

> Uncaught Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 50, got 48.

My node version is the 6.6 and my npm version is 3.10.3.

Comment: Definitely follow [these steps](https://gist.github.com/craigvantonder/f59277cd788f8aa755e3bdbe5d21f08e).

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a try for [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) package and rebuild the sqlite package for using with electron against electron headers (electron uses patched version of nodejs)

Look at [instruction](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md) as well.

Also take a look for this answer [How to use sqlite3 module with electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504307/how-to-use-sqlite3-module-with-electron)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than renaming the folder, which lead to an error similar to yours, I had success by specifying the version of Electron by adding `-v` to my build command:

`./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -v 1.4.13`

This created the `electron-v1.4-win32-x64` it was looking for, instead of `electron-v1.6-win32-x64`, and the module versions lined up correctly.