# Best way to store data in a local Data Base in an application built using Angularjs and Electron

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, electron

I am building an app using angularjs which is then ported to multiple platform using electron. The app needs a DB to store large set of data so which storage option is better. i want to use sqlite but will it work or correctly build in electron

Comment: How does this have anything to do with electronics??

Comment: He/She was talking about Electron and not Electronics!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data in indexeddb. It is fast and completely html5 technologies.

Although indexeddb may be tough to understand for some users, so you can use any idb library which makes things easy for you.

Check out example of storing data using indexeddb library jsstore in electron - https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/JsStore/tree/master/examples/electron

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Sqlite with electron. Check out this answer which has further links and details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230765/324143

Comment: does sqlite have any limit when using with electron want to use nedb but read it has db size limit and it loads the db into ram so its gonna be a problem for large databases