# NodeJS - Cannot find module in child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to use a child_process to perform a long task in the background without slowing down the whole application.

I'm having trouble requiring the sqlite3 module inside of my child_process.
Here's my code:

main.js

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
const fork = child_process.fork('child.js');
```

child.js

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('data.db');
```

Here's what I get:

module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'A:\myretail\clictill_electron\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\myretail\clictill_electron\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\myretail\clictill_electron\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:190:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "clictill_electron",
    "productName": "Clictill",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "child_process": "^1.0.2",
        "electron": "^1.8.4",
        "fibers": "^2.0.2",
        "node-gyp": "^3.6.2",
        "node-pre-gyp": "^0.8.0",
        "request": "^2.85.0",
        "sqlite3": "^3.1.13",
        "sync": "^0.2.5"
    },
    "build": {
        "files": [
            "app/**/*",
            "node_modules/**/*",
            "package.json"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools && npm install --global node-gyp && setx PYTHON \"%USERPROFILE%\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe\" && npm config set python PYTHON",
        "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -v 1.8.2 -w sqlite3 -p",
        "start": "electron .",
        "release": "build",
        "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron-builder": "^10.8.1",
        "electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3"
    }
}
```

Any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: You have run `npm install` correct?

Comment: Yes, my app is working correctly, I can require every module everywhere, I just have trouble with the sqlite3 module when it's required inside a child_process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sqlite3 module with electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504307/how-to-use-sqlite3-module-with-electron)

Comment: This is not the same problem, I got my app working with SQLite, my only problem is when I'm trying to use SQLite **inside a child_process**

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am having the same issue (although in my case it's cypress complaining about not finding electron)

Answer (score -5):

Have you checked your path to see if the sqlite3 module exists where it should?

otherwise i would do `npm child_process uninstall --save`,  then do `npm child_process install --save`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for such a quick reply! I just checked the path, and the file actually is in the folder "node-v**59**-win32-x64" instead of "node-v**57**-win32-x64". What does this number represent? (sorry I'm a very new Node user)

Comment: it is the node version package you are using for the project, so in your package.json, looks like it is trying to look v57 in v59 folder. If you ammend your package.json to suit it should run

Comment: Also I tried to reinstall the child_process module as you suggested, I have the same result

Comment: I don't see anything weird in package.json, is there a way to manually specify the node version package somewhere so that it looks in the right folder?

Comment: This gives the same result :(

Comment: try npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source

Comment: Still not working. I also tried removing the node_modules folder and running npm install, still gives me the same problem...

Comment: npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

Comment: try the following in sequence https://www.laurivan.com/make-electron-work-with-sqlite3/

Comment: This gives me the same error, with the wrong node version. I'm really lost on this, because SQLite works perfectly fine in my app, unless it's required in a child process...

Comment: This is incorrect child_process is a built in module.