# Webpack Error: please install sqlite3 package manually

Tags: javascript, webpack, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I'm building an application with Electron and Sequelize. I started to configure my database, then, I've received this error:

> Uncaught Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually
>       at new ConnectionManager (/home/matheusdrdj/Documentos/Git/personal- 
>       management/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/con…:31)
>       at new SqliteDialect (/home/matheusdrdj/Documentos/Git/personal- 
>       management/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/ind…:14)
>       at new Sequelize (/home/matheusdrdj/Documentos/Git/personal- 
>       management/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:239)
>       at eval (index.js?17a5:3)
>       at Object. (renderer.js:1084)
>       at **webpack_require** (renderer.js:680)
>       at fn (renderer.js:90)
>       at eval (index.js?21f1:1)
>       at Object. (renderer.js:1077)
>       at **webpack_require** (renderer.js:680)
>       at fn (renderer.js:90)
>       at eval (main.js?3b76:1)
>       at Object. (renderer.js:918)
>       at **webpack_require** (renderer.js:680)
>       at fn (renderer.js:90)
>       at Object. (renderer.js:835)
>       at **webpack_require** (renderer.js:680)
>       at renderer.js:726
>       at renderer.js:729

I have installed sqlite3 globally and localy, tested it on the console and it's working fine. But, my application doesn't even load the screen.

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.7",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^2.5.3",
    "vuetify": "1.0.0",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "0.1.2",
    "cfonts": "^1.1.3",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.5",
    "electron-builder": "^19.19.1",
    "electron-debug": "^1.4.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "multispinner": "^0.2.1",
    "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
}
```

I cannot figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Electron sqlite3 has to be built with electron-builder.

[How to use sqlite3 module with electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504307/how-to-use-sqlite3-module-with-electron?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
and https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder
both recommend adding this to your `package.json`

```
"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
```

This will rebuild all native binaries everytime you install a new package.