# Uncaught Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually error after packaging the app

Tags: sqlite, electron, electron-packager

After I package an electron app with electron-packager using this commande from npm scripts :

```
electron-packager . Gestion-ecole-sportive 
--overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --asar
--icon=assets/image/icons/conApp.ico --prune=true 
--out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE 
--version-string.FileDescription=CE 
--version-string.ProductName="Gestion d'école sportive"
```

Knowing that it's the same machine that I build the app on it, and it was working fine in the development process

And when I start the app, it's shows, but I found an error of sqlite3 in the console of the dev tools :

`Uncaught Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually`

and it's coming from sequelize configuration line code :

```
sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'config/db/db_ecole.db'
})
```

devDependencies and dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.8",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.6",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.5",
    "node-gyp": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
    "exceljs": "^2.0.1",
    "gijgo": "^1.9.13",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "sequelize": "^5.19.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try an electron rebuild? Something along the lines of:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -w sqlite3
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Should I run this line befor the electron-packager ?

Comment: Yea try running this command independently. Also, check out this link as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3#custom-builds-and-electron

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it didn't work, but I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50262876/8665772) and I  used electron-builder instead, because it build the sqlite module while packaging the electron app, and also give an .exe installer for windows