# How to connect to the database in a standalone Electron Angular app?

Tags: angular, electron

I want to build a small app using:

- Electron
- Angular
- SQLite

I am trying to connect to an **SQLite DB** and I found that there are multiple approaches.
There are 2 that interested me:

1. Using a library such as [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).
2. Using IPC that Electron library makes available: **IpcRender** and **IpcMain**

For now I've tried the first approach. Using [this repository](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/tree/main) as starting point I get errors after `npm install sqlite3` such as:

```
./node_modules/tar/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/use-native.js:1:11-24 - 
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '.../angular-electron/node_modules/tar/node_modules/mkdirp/lib'
```

For the second approach I found [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/creating-an-electron-app-using-angular-and-sqlite3-24ca7d892810/) published on **Feb 15, 2019** which uses [electron-forge](https://www.electronforge.io/) to generate the project with **Angular 2** template and for the database connection it uses **IpcRender**.

I don't understand if I am doing something wrong, or if this library isn't compatible with the project or if I should switch to the second approach.

How is the second approach with **IpcMain** and **IpcRender** using **typeorm** library compared with using **sqlite3** directly in an **Angular Service**, performance wise and best practice?

Comment: The sqlite3 library should work just fine. The error you included leads me to believe that the `moduleResolution` property from the `compilerOptions` inside your `tsconfig.json` is not set to `"node"`. Can you double check that?

Comment: I've just checked and it is set `"moduleResolution": "node"`. Also it is a matter of what approach to use, it's not very clear to me what are the implications. A very important point it that I am **not** using any server such as **NodeJS** or **.NET**, I want to **avoid** internet connections

Comment: You should be able to use sqlite to manage a database locally. Can you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011612/1440005)? The problem looks similar.

Comment: I've checked that article before posting this question and it wasn't clear for me if this is the right approach as it is mentioned in [the response](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272#issuecomment-341428996). That's why I decided to post this question to have a better understanding of what approach should I chose. I am not trying only to make it work temporarily, I want to understand future implications.

Comment: From what I noticed in [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230765/1440005) it looks like sqlite needs to be rebuilt in order to work with electron. Feel free to give it a shot, maybe you'll get it to work. There seem to be also pure javascript alternatives, but are not as performant as native sqlite.

Comment: The [github readme of the sqlite3 library](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3#custom-builds-and-electron) also lists some instructions on how to go about adding it to an electron project, maybe that can be of help.

Comment: I updated this post with a more specific question. Can you take a look please? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using sqlite3 in my angular electron app. These are the steps that I followed for implementation:

1. Download sqlite3 in your project using npm.
2. In your main.js file import sqlite3 using require.

   const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose()
3. Create a db file in your project and use it to connect to the database.

   let db = new sqlite.Database('./your_file_name.db', (err) => {
   if (err) {

   }

   console.log('Connected to sqlite database')
   })
4. Now you can simply use the db object to run sql queries using db.run callback function.

Comment: From my POV, this implementation that you are preseinting is very ambiguous. From what I've documented until now, the logical implementation is the second approach with **IpcMain** and **IpcRender**. It can also be used an ORM like **TypeORM** which I've tried using but with no success. In this conditions I've decided to use a separate service for **DB management** and call it with **REST** and for **OS API** I've decided to use this **IpcMain, IpcRender** approach via the **ElectronService**.